# readFileSync returns empty buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider myFile.json content as below:

```
{ a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0,
  d: 0 
}
```

In nodejs, I have a block of code to read and parse this file, and then write new data to it:

```js
const myFile = fs.readFileSync('../path/to/file');
console.log(myFile);
const data = JSON.parse(myFile);
console.log(data);
// provide some new data saved in newData....
fs.writeFile(statisticalFile, JSON.stringify(newData), err => {
   if (err) {
     throw err;
   }
});
```

sometimes it is successfully executed, but sometimes not.
Here is what code prints in successfull manner:

```js
<Buffer 7b ... >
{ a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4 }
```

And here is what code prints in failed manner (It seems reasult of `readFileSync` method is an empty buffer):

```js
<Buffer >
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    ....
```

why this happens, although I use sync version of read file?

Comment: an empty buffer means the file has no content.. and if it happens "sometimes", then something is removing the content.. check how this files is being used in your code. node.js is async, so maybe you read it before something else writes the data..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text from file, you have to provide the encoding

```
const myFile = fs.readFileSync('../path/to/file', 'utf8');
```

Now you can parse it with `JSON.parse`

Comment: Thanks, but if the problem is about encoding, why this error happened only sometimes? Indeed before parsing it sometimes read as an empty buffer.

Comment: I guess that the file is empty if it's empty